# Pequeno Back Office

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou a criar uma pequeno *back office* em PHP, MySQL e HTML e estou com uma pequena duvida.

Tabela:

```
IDNoticia
Dia
Mes
Titulo 
Noticia
```

Depois no HTML/PHP vou fazer `echo` para mostrar o dia, mês, Titulo E Noticia mas tenho uma duvida em relação ao Anexo.

Porque podem haver noticias que tem um anexo como tenho neste HTML

```
 <a href="#">Titulo Teste</a>
```

Posso colocar o Anexo também no MySQL e depois como consigo chamar o MySQL para o `href`?

Comment: Por anexo você quer dizer uma imagem? A imagem da notícia?

Comment: Pode ser uma imagem, um PDF, uma outra pagina.

Comment: A ideia de guardar anexos na Base de dados não é muito boa. Seria melhor ter uma pasta publica com os anexos. Exemplo: http://www.seudominio.br/anexos/anexo1. Poderá sim guardar na base de dados o nome do anexo em questão.

Comment: Pra começar que a relação da notícia com o anexo deveria ser 1-para-n, no caso de você precisar de mais de um anexo por notícia. De qualquer forma, é interessante discriminar o tipo de anexo por meio de uma coluna, o caminho virtual do anexo em outra e salvar o arquivo no arquivo de sistemas, ao invés de salvá-lo no banco de dados.

Comment: Posso colocar uma pasta com com o Anexo (PDF) porque vai ser o que vou usar mais.
A unica coisa que tinha de colocar no Mysql era o caminho

Comment: Sim @ChrisAdler o caminho, ou então só mesmo o nome do anexo, se o caminho for o mesmo para todos os anexos.

Comment: Então será apenas o caminho. Então no Href basta acrescentar um href="echo:titulo.pdf"
Por exemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Olá!
É indicado guardar no banco de Dados o caminho/referência para o arquivo.

Uma vez guardado, no seu href, você poderá colocar o conteúdo da coluna anexo e ele já estará ligado ao seu arquivo.

Lembrando que você precisa verificar se o arquivo está realmente no caminho indicado.

Comment: É isso aí mesmo. É mais indicado colocar somente o caminho do anexo do banco e fazer o upload do anexo para uma pasta específica.